# Disable free shipping until a specific date in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, date, woocommerce, shipping-method

I want to disable free shipping until a certain date in WooCommerce using PHP only.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'disable_free_shipping_until_certain_date', 10, 2 );

function disable_free_shipping_until_certain_date($rates, $package) {
    $current_date = date("Y-m-d");
    $disable_date = strtotime('2024-02-25');
    $disable_date = date('Y-m-d',$disable_date);
    
    if($current_date < $disable_date){
        unset( $rates['free_shipping'] );
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

This is the PHP snippet I made, but it doesn't work. 
Why I can't make it work? 
What do I need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the correct shipping rate ID *(array key)* for your free shipping method in the current shipping zone, to make it work in your code.

Try the following, to disable free shipping until a specific defined date threshold:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'disable_free_shipping_until_specific_date', 10, 2 );
function disable_free_shipping_until_specific_date( $rates, $package ) {
    $threshold_date = '2024-02-25'; // Threshold date until free shipping is disabled

    // Loop through shipping rates for the current shipping package
    foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {
        // Targeting free shipping and specific date
        if ( 'free_shipping' === $rate->method_id && time() <= strtotime($threshold_date) ) {
            unset($rates[$rate_key]); // Remove shipping rate
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

**Important:** You will have to empty your cart to refresh shipping method cache.